# Bold math symbols in chapter headers and symbol for the Laplacian

Tags: header-footer, bold

I recently asked a question in this forum on how to get bold math symbols in a chapter header and I got recommended the packages
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

The two problems I've got are: Firstly in my headers throughout a certain chapter the math symbol is still shown fat while the "normal" text ist not...

Secondly I defined a symbol for the Laplacian via \newcommand*\Laplace{\mathop{{}\bigtriangleup}\nolimits}...but while using those packages named above, the Laplacian is displayed incredibly small...I've tried $\Delta$ of course but I don't like it at all!

Anybody got an idea how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The line of code `\AddToHook{bfseries}{\boldmath}` makes math bold whenever the surrounding text is bold. It requires a (relatively) recent LaTeX installation, though.

Comment: Thank you very much - as I'm using Overleaf the version is no problem - this works fine and solves my first question! :-) Thanks